# Декоратор по типу route во flask

Tags: python, декоратор

Моя задача - сделать простой в читаемости код, который будет обрабатывать сообщение функцией, с аргументом в декораторе, равном этому сообщению
Как я это представляю:

```
@my_decorator(message='мое сообщение')
def hi():
    print('Твое сообщение!')

process_message('мое сообщение')
# Вывод: > Твое сообщение!
```

Как это возможно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, чего вы хотите, то так:

```
class MessageHandler:
    _funcs = {}

    def process_message(msg):
        MessageHandler._funcs[msg]()

    def deco(msg):
        def inner_deco(func):
            MessageHandler._funcs[msg] = func
            return func
        return inner_deco


@MessageHandler.deco(msg='мое сообщение')
def hi():
    print('Твое сообщение!')

MessageHandler.process_message('мое сообщение')
# Вывод: > Твое сообщение!
```

Можно сделать и без класса, чтобы синтаксис был именно как в вашем вопросе, но я рекомендую использовать всё-таки класс.

И ещё - в моём случае никак не обрабатывается ситуация, в которой process_message будет вызван с сообщением, для которого не создана функция. В реальном коде этот случай стоит как-то особо обрабатывать.